# jQuery's .ajaxSend: can't add data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use `$(document).ajaxSend(...)` to dynamically add data (POST args) to some Ajax requests, when necessary.
Adding data works when some datas have been defined in an `$.ajax(...)` call. But if no data has been defined in the `$.ajax` setting, my `$.ajaxSend` can't add data to the settings.

Here is my `$.ajaxSend` interceptor:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, request, settings) {
    if(settings.csrfIntention) {
        var requestToken = {
            intention: settings.csrfIntention,
            hash: self.tokens[settings.csrfIntention]
        }

        if(!settings.data) {
            settings.data = '_token=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(requestToken));
        }
        else if(typeof(settings.data) == 'string') {
            settings.data += '&_token=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(requestToken));
        }
        else if(!settings.data._token) {
            settings.data._token = requestToken;
        }
    }
});
```

And an example of $.ajax call that works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: opts.close.url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: { foo:'bar' },
    csrfIntention: 'ajax_close_ticket',
    success: function(data) { ... }
});
```

The `$.ajaxSend` works and `settings.data` is set to:

```
foo=bar&_token=%7B%22intention%22%3A%22ajax_close_ticket%22%2C%22hash%22%3A%22uXV1AeZwm-bZL3KlYER-Dowzzd1QmCmaT6aJFjWLpLY%22%7D
```

Serverside, I can retrieve the two fields: foo and _token.

Now, if I remove the `data` object in the `$.ajax` call, the output of `$.ajaxSend` seems Ok, too:

```
 _token=%7B%22intention%22%3A%22ajax_close_ticket%22%2C%22hash%22%3A%225cK2WIegwI6u8K_FrxywuauWOo79xvhIcASQrZ9QPZQ%22%7D
```

Yet, the server don't receive my _token field :(

Another interesting fact: when I have the two fields, the Chromium dev tools under the Network tab displays the two fields under a "Form Data" title. When _token is alone, "Form Data" is replaced by "Request Payload".

**Edit:** just understood why _token is not interpreted by the server. If no data has been previously set in `$.ajax` call, jQuery does not add the right `Content-Type` in HTTP headers, it set it to `text/plain` instead of  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. How can I force jQuery to add this header?

**Edit 2:** Solution found. Will post an answer to help other people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I answer my question after only 10 minutes...

In HTTP, the form arguments are sent into the request body, under the headers. The header `Content-Type` should be present to declare the data type. When this header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the server will understand that you sent a form and will parse the request body as a GET URL (you know, the `foo=bar&key=val` format).

jQuery adds this header automatically when you set a `data` object into the `$.ajax` call. Then it passes the request to the `$.ajaxSend` callback, which adds its proper fields.

When no `data` has been provided in request settings, jQuery do not add an unnecessary `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded` in the request headers. Then, when you append the request body into your `$.ajaxSend` callback, jQuery do not check the data again and declares the content as `text/plain`. The server has nothing to do with `text/plain` so it does not interpret the body data as form fields.

You can obviously force jQuery to change the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, let's take the code of my original post :

```
if(!settings.data) {
    settings.data = '_token=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(requestToken));
}
```

Now add the right header:

```
if(!settings.data) {
    settings.data = '_token=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(requestToken));
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my bad English

I believe that the solution to his case would be the use of the function "ajaxSetup"

```
var requestToken = {
        intention: settings.csrfIntention,
        hash: self.tokens[settings.csrfIntention]
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    data : {
        _token: requestToken
    }
});
```

this way all your orders took the data as the desire

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add the _token on all requests. I think `$.ajaxSend` is more adapted to my situation. However, I understood the problem (read my edits into the OP), I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```
var requestToken = {
        intention: settings.csrfIntention,
        hash: self.tokens[settings.csrfIntention]
    }
var myForm = {};
myForm['_token'] = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(requestToken));
```

In your ajax call:

```
myForm['foo'] = 'bar';
$.ajax({
    url: opts.close.url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: myForm,
    csrfIntention: 'ajax_close_ticket',
    success: function(data) { ... }
});
//This sends foo and _token
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a solution (read my edits into the OP). Anyway, your solution would not have been easily implementable into my application (I simplified the code). Thank you anyway and sorry for making you waste time!

Comment: No problem @MorganTouvereyQuilling ...i'm gald to help anyway... cheers :)